# Advise on what else I could inclide in my Ruby WebApp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rest, web-applications, devise

hope you're all well. I have built an app that takes feedback from a user, which they can create and view but only their own feedbacks. Admins can view all feedbakcks. Admins can create users and create feedbacks, edit destroy delete etc (they have power over everything). It looks brilliant. I've used devise for authentication and cancan for authorization. What else can I include in this app to make it look better or function better or anything else that can make this app usefull in any way at all any ideas anyone? here is the database and relationship between the two:

User has_many :feedbacks

Feedbacks belong_to :user

Cheers guys.

Comment: That is a super general question. I would suggest rephrasing it. Are looking for something related to the databases? (since you mentioned it)

Comment: reddit.com/r/rails may be a more suitable place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: I would agree with the other users. Asking that type of question is extremely general since answering that type of question would depend on way too many factors. Also, if your relationships can be summed up in two lines then your system is probably too simple to be useful in the real world. Especially user feedback systems. It's not just about capturing the data, its about conceptualizing it and mining that data for useful content. My only suggestion in general is that you should look into how to mine all of your "users" data. Yet again, this completely depends on your direction.